# Problem with my Bootstrap Navbar (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm currently working on a website.
My Navbar is only working on the index.html page. When I'm on aboutme.html in the webbrowser, **I can't click on any button on my navbar**. I copied the standard Bootstrap navbar and styled it to the middle.

style.css (in css/style.css):

```
/* Style Navbar */

.navbar-brand {
    /* logo */
    margin-left: 20vw;
}

/* .active {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: underline;
} */

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20vw;
}
```

I'm not using a special js file

Comment: Your blog.html file is inside `sites` folder so change `<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>` to `<script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my mistake.
Beside of the fact that the jquery path was wrong, the navbar was in the background. The columns from the bootstrap row I had on the bottom was covering the navbar.
I styled the navbar with

```
navbar {
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to load the scripts you marked with comments.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Second solution: Try to check if the location of the `../css/style.css` file is correct

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

Comment: The first I commented is my local bootstrap file that doesn't work (idk why). The second one is an old bootstrap file (version 4.0.0). These are the same links as on my index page (there it works). The location of the stylesheet is right.

Comment: You can paste this code somewhere to show how it works, paste the code on eg. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar buttons not working because of jquery file location.
you need to change your location code for blog and contact page like this:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

and you need change your script location:

```
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem but that's a bad mistake too.